# How to get and set column number based on value in source spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to copy a range (L2:L9) to another spreadsheet based on a data validation selection (ID #) in a specific cell (G11) on the source spreadsheet.

The ID#s are all in alphanumeric order on the target spreadsheet along row 5, so all I need is to get the column number that corresponds to the choice made in the data validation field.

Before I had to convert the ID#s to Alphanumeric values, I simply had numeric values and the script worked fine. Now I'm having trouble converting the script to work with this modification.

```
function Submit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // ss = source spreadsheet
  var source_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  if (source_sheet.getName() == "Pre-Season CC") {
  var SRange = source_sheet.getRange('L2:L9');
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MpKdxFyBrVQT3EumePQvtCZpgzcDW5xlYe4B1DKZCA8');
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName('Pre-Season');
  var idNumber = source_sheet.getRange('Pre-Season CC!G11').getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < idNumber.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < idNumber.length;j++){
    if (target_sheet[4][j] == idNumber){
      Logger.log((j+1))
      return j+1;
  target_sheet.getRange('B6:B13').offset(0,valueA1 = ss.getRange('Pre-Season!G11').getValue(idNumber)+1).setValues(SData);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At that point, I need the data copied from source spreadsheet onto the target spreadsheet in it's designated column, according to the ID#. Please help!

Comment: I think that providing a sample Spreadsheet will help users think of your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
function Submit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // ss = source spreadsheet
  var source_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (source_sheet.getName() == 'Pre-Season CC') {
    // source sheet items
    var SData = source_sheet.getRange('L2:L9').getValues();
    var idNumber = source_sheet.getRange('Pre-Season CC!G11').getValue();

    // target sheet items
    var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MpKdxFyBrVQT3EumePQvtCZpgzcDW5xlYe4B1DKZCA8');
    var target_sheet = targetSS.getSheetByName('Pre-Season');
    // 5 = row where IDs are
    var TData = target_sheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, target_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    // column index of #ID in target sheet
    var colIndex = TData.indexOf(idNumber) + 1;

    // write data in that column, rows from 6 to 13
    target_sheet.getRange(6, colIndex, SData.length, 1).setValues(SData);
  }
}
```